# How to access another object in Jacskon custom serializer?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I want to use a custom `Jackson` serializer to write a property value which is determined on another value in the model. The problem is that the values are within different objects. Here is a simplified version of my model.

```
public class MyModel {
    private ObjectA objectA;
    private Object objectB
....
}

public class ObjectA {
    private String myValue; //this is the property that will determine the value in ObjectB
    ......
}

public class ObjectB {
    @JsonSerialize(using=MyCustomSerializer.class)
    private String myOtherValue;// this this the value that will be use my custom serializer
    .....
}

//this is my CustomSerialier

public class MyCustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
         String myOtherValue = (String) value;
         //to process 'myOtherValue' I need access to 'myValue' in ObjectA
    ........
}
```

}

I would rather not put a custom serializer on `MyModel` as the model is very large with lots of nested objects, so writing that out in a customer serializer would be more that I want to do. Is there are way to access other objects in the model using a custom serializer without having to set it at the top level object?

Comment: And what about making `ObjectB` implement `JsonSerializable`?

Comment: Not sure exactly how that works, will look at the docs.

Comment: Rereading your problem again, it doesn't appear that this will be the solution though. Except maybe if your `ObjectA` is passed as a constructor argument to `ObjectB` and there is, say, a getter for `myValue`.

Comment: If I implement JsonSerializer can I make changes to the model and use jgen.writeObject(this), or do I have to write each individual property
?

Comment: I can get access to the values I need when I implement JsonSerializable.

Comment: If you modify `ObjectB`, you will have to modify the `serialize*()` methods accordingly.

Comment: I have implementend JsonSerializableWithType in my model object and overridden the serialize method, but it not getting called?

Comment: Uhm, are you using Jackson 2.x?

Comment: You should create custom deserializer for root object. Could you show example `JSON` which you are trying to parse?

Comment: I don't want to add it to the root object as my model is very big I would need to write custom code for the whole model.